# Какая конструкция работает быстрее IN или EXISTS?

Tags: sql, oracle

В реляционных СУБД есть две конструкции `IN` и `EXISTS`.

В случае если подзапрос, с которым производится сравнение не содержит записей с `NULL`, то по сути не важно, какую из них  использовать.

Вопрос, какая более производительная?

Comment: `exists` работает не медленнее, т.к. должна вернуть по сути только флаг есть/нет и всё. А `in` вернуть весь список. Но лучше конкретно замерить время работы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если in заведомо выбирает одну строку - то время должно быть одинаково. Вообще видя `exists` оптимизатор может сам догадаться, что выполняемый внутри exists подзапрос надо выполнять с оптимизацией FIRST_ROW, т.е. для быстрого получения первой записи и после получения этой записи он собственно остановится. В случае `in` оптимизатор может пойти по другому пути, для более быстрого получения всех строк. И этот путь может быть не таким как для получения одной строки.

Кроме того чисто теоретически в случае `in` оптимизатор может начать выполнение с подзапроса и потом пытаться выбрать записи из основной таблицы по условию. В случае `exists` оптимизатор может решить идти по основной таблице, а для каждой ее записи проверять подзапрос. Но на практике оптимизатор не забудет посмотреть какие индексы есть в наличии, посмотреть статистику по таблицам и индексам и примет решение исходя из этой информации.

Но какой именно путь окажется на самом деле более быстрым предсказать в общем случае невозможно. Необходимо учитывать множество факторов. Если вас интересует скорость работы запроса, то для каждого запроса надо смотреть план выполнения и если план не устраивает пробовать разные варианты.

А единого рецепта что какая то конструкция быстрее или медленнее быть не может. Надо так же обратить внимание на то, что разные релизы СУБД (даже не крупные версии) могут по разному оптимизировать тот или иной запрос.

Comment: В частности, эффект от `LIMIT 1` в подзапросе с in может свести разницу к нулю.

Comment: @D-side Там тег Oracle, а в оракле нет LIMIT :)

Comment: @Mike, ну тогда `ROWNUM = 1` в блоке `WHERE` -  разницы практически никакой, семантика только. ) Все понимают о чем речь, независимо от  конкретного диалекта.

Answer (score 3):

[Условия](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Conditions.html) в SQL запросе, о которых идёт речь в вопросе, содержат выражение и возвращают логическое значение. Они должны соответствовать условиям поставленной задачи, или др. словами - способствовать получению желаемого результата. Но они не имеют такого свойства как - *быстрое* или *медленное*.

> [EXISTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html)
> TRUE if a subquery returns at least one row.

> [IN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html)
> It tests a value for membership in a list of values or subquery (Equal-to-any-member-of test).

Попробуем с такими таблицами:

```
create table t1 (id, code unique) as 
    select rownum, chr (65+mod (rownum-1,26))||lpad (rownum,7,'0') 
    from dual connect by level<=1000  
/
create table t2 (id, code unique)  as select * from t1
/
```

И сформулируем две задачи, соответствующие  описаниям условий выше:

1. из таблицы `t1` надо получить все записи, для которых в таблице `t2` существует как минимум одна запись с тем же кодом
2. из таблицы `t1` надо получить все записи с кодами, которые содержаться в листе кодов, полученных из таблицы `t2`

Составим запросы для решния этих задач и посммотрим как они выполняются:
*Запрос #1*

```
select * from t1 /* case #1 */
    where EXISTS (
    select null from t2      
    where t2.code = t1.code)
/
1000 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4138308017
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |              |  1000 | 22000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |              |  1000 | 22000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1           |  1000 | 13000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| SYS_C0011614 |     1 |     9 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - access("T2"."CODE"="T1"."CODE")
```

*Запрос #2*

```
select * from t1 /* case #2 */
    where t1.code IN (
    select t2.code from t2)
/
1000 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4138308017
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |              |  1000 | 22000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |              |  1000 | 22000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1           |  1000 | 13000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| SYS_C0011614 |     1 |     9 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - access("T1"."CODE"="T2"."CODE")
```

Как видим, оптимизатор посмотрел, что надо получить в результате каждого запроса, какие индексы построены, статистику на таблицы и индексы, и в результате, составил **один план выполнения** для обоих задач. Тем самым, посчитав, что для их вполнения так будет *быстрей* и *эффективней*.

**Когда же лучше использовать `EXISTS`, а когда `IN`?**

Дополним обе задачи выше доп. условием: *... и только с кодами, начинaюшимся с буквы `A`*. Так как надо всегда стремится ограничить кол-во записей вовращаемых на каждом уровне запроса, то даже как-то логично предположить, что:

1. если это условие применимо к главному запросу, то лучше использовать `EXISTS`

   ```
   select * from t1 /* case #1 */
   where t1.code like 'A%' 
   and exists (
       select null from t2
       where t2.code = t1.code)
   /
   ```
2. если оно по больше подходит к подзапросу, то лучшим выбором будет `IN`

   ```
   select * from t1 /* case #2 */
   where t1.code in (
       select t2.code from t2
       where t2.code like 'A%')
   /
   ```

Не стоит удивляться, что оптимизатор и на этот раз создаст один план, ведь обе таблицы идентичны.

Пробуйте оба варианта запроса на реальных данных (или максимально приближенном к ним примере). Сравните планы выполнения запросов. Задайте новый вопрос с примером данных и структурой таблиц, если есть подозрение, что оптимизатор выбрал не самый эффективный план и вследствии того, производительность отличается от ожидаемой.

Answer (score 0):

Если отбросить тему про то что некоторые условия могут описаны только с помощью in, то при небольшом количестве возвращаемых записей в in и небольшом количестве записей в таблице из которой ведется выборка, разница будет смешной или даже не заметной. Все изменится тогда, когда либо в таблице, из которой ведется выборка, много записей, либо в таблице из которой выбирает in много записей, или и там и там их много. В этом случае, как я понял, появляется огромная разница за счет того, что exists находит первую подходящую запись и на этом заканчивает свою работу, если есть по соот. полю индекс, то это просто спросить значение в индексе и все, если мы говорим об in, то он сначала выбирает запросом все подходящие записи, а потом в полученном наборе начинает лопатить процессором в поисках первой подходящей записи, а позицию этой записи предугадать невозможно, т.е. в среднем будет перелопачиваться половина набора вернувшегося в in для каждой записи из выбираемой таблицы и это если построитель плана запроса применит in в конце накладываемых условий выборки, а не в начале, что приведет к тому, что количество проверок будет еще больше. В такой ситуации, логично было бы построить по значениям возвращенным in на лету индекс, но этого почему-то не делается, по крайней мере в PG.

Немного сравнительной статистики, есть 2 таблицы, одна 2 ляма записей, другая 40 лямов записей, выборка из первой таблицы всех записей отсутствующих во второй, exists 4-5 сек, in 6-7 часов, в результирующей выборке около 900K записей.